# Which answer should I accept if the rules are ambiguous on the matter?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Recently I posted [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131210/is-it-possible-to-possess-a-non-humanoid-creature-with-a-combination-of-true-pol) and as a result received two contradictary answers, but since game rules are a slightly ambigious on this particular topic, arguments for each of the answers are partially true (at least to the degree where the answer could not be discarded right away as a wrong one).

Users looking for an answer usually (from my experience showing RPG.SE to several friends of mine) look only at the accepted answer, not bothering themselves to scroll down further to check any other answer.

Not to mention that accepted answer mark marks an answer as the most *correct* (in RAW context).

**What can/should I do in this current situation?**

---

***Possible solutions:***

- Accept an answer with most upvotes;
- Accept an answer I *myself* consider correct;
- Do not accept any answer;
- Accept an answer with most upvotes, accumulate enough reputation to reward another answer with bounty;
- Something else.

Answer (score 26):

### For now, neither

It is completely okay not to accept any answer if you feel the issue is not clear. You are under no obligation to reward the highest voted answer either. The two systems have different purposes.

### Try them

"Accept" is also there to indicate what has actually *worked* for the querent. If you try the answers out and see that one solves your problem, accept that.

Answer (score 7):

If a question generates two highly upvoted answers, that themselves are mutually exclusive with each other (i.e. "yes, this is possible" vs "no, this is not possible"), then the safest conclusion you can draw is to assert that the decision really boils down to DM decision making. D&D, especially 5e (the system you posted that question for) relies strongly on the DM decision making process for resolving rule conflicts, and that's inherent to the system. Sometimes, there's not going to be an answer that definitively proves or disproves a given idea/combo/whatever.

Ultimately, "Accepting" an answer is about asserting that that answer is most helpful *to you* for resolving the issue. If one of the answers resolves the issue for you, you can consider accepting it. Other times, it's fine to simply let it be, with the understanding that there really just isn't one defacto-correct answer.

Comment: If the answer boils down to “it's up to the DM”, that also suggests that there's room for a third answer to that effect.

Comment: I have a little flag that says Xirema is a new contributor.  You've been with us for a while.  Does that flag mean it's a first meta post?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yeah, I assumed that was why it flagged me.